# How to write a custom getter if class properties are defined in the constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been writing an app where at first I declared the class signature as below

```
data class MClass(val id: Int = 0,val descr: String, val timestamp: Long)
```

Now a need was created where I must have a custom getter for a field above. How can I write this custom getter? I know that If otherwise I could write something like

```
data class(){
     val id=0
     val descr = ""
     get() = descr + "append smth"

     val timestamp:Long = 0

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like below:

```
data class MClass(val id: Int = 0, private val descr: String, val timestamp: Long)  {
    val description: String
        get() = descr + "append smth"
}
```

Comment: @Libathos No, notice that descr is private now, so using my example you will access propety calling MClass.description, which is a different variable with different value

Comment: great didn't notice the private part. Thank you, lastly I just want to make sure, my custom getter cannot have an argument, is that correct?

Comment: @Libathos, you are right, property getter cannot have parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like that:

```
data class MClass(val id: Int = 0, private val _descr: String, val timestamp: Long) {
    val descr: String
        get() = _descr + "append something"
}
```